# Vimeo videos do not load

Tags: javascript

I would like to use integrated Vimeo videos on a page and have them start playing as soon as the page is loaded and when the first video has finished, the second one starts. In my code I have an array of video ids but my problem is the video does not load.

```
 <div id="headervideo"></div>
<script src="https://player.vimeo.com/api/player.js"></script>

<script>
//====================
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function(event) {
    var videos = ['240512614', '227735391']; //  videos ids
    var options = {
        width: 640,
        loop: true
    };
    var player = new Vimeo.Player('headervideo', options);
        playMovie(player, videos)
})//end function

//====================
var playMovie = function(player, videos) {
    if(!videos.length){
      return false;
    }

        var video = videos.shift();
        alert (video)
    player.loadVideo(videos).then(function(id) {
            alert("the video successfully loaded ")
        player.getEnded().then(function(ended) {
            playMovie(player, videos)
        }).catch(function(error) {
            console.warn(error)
        });
    }).catch(function(error) {
        console.warn(error);
    });
}//end function
//====================
</script>
```

Comment: What is the error message on the browser console?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your first issue lies in

```
new Vimeo.Player('headervideo', options);
```

You cannot create a Vimeo.Player without specifying a video in the options object (or as an html attribute on an associated element).

So, specifying either:

```
var video = videos.shift();
var options = {
    width: 640,
    loop: true,
    id: video
}
```

or:

```
var options = {
    width: 640,
    loop: true,
    id: videos[0]
}
```

Will let you load the video.

But this will raise your second issue, that `playMovie` will not wait for your currently playing video to finish, but rather swap the video out immediately. `getEnded()` is not a synchronously blocking function.

What you want to do is instead listen on the [`ended`](https://github.com/vimeo/player.js#ended) event. And also turn of the `loop: true` as this will disable the `ended` event

```
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function(event) {
    window.videos = ['240512614', '227735391']; //  videos ids
    var video = videos.shift();
    var options = {
        width: 640,
        loop: false,
        id: video

    };
    window.player = new Vimeo.Player('headervideo', options);
    window.player.on('ended', playNext);
    window.player.play();
})//end function

//====================
var playNext= function() {
    alert('foo');
    if(!window.videos.length){
      return false;
    }

    var video = window.videos.shift();
    alert (video);
    player.loadVideo(video).then(function(id) {
        alert("the video "+id+" successfully loaded ");
        player.play();
    }).catch(function(error) {
        console.warn(error)
    });
}//end function
```

Comment: I try it but the  video finish immediately when the page loaded

Comment: so,  now video load but the second not start when the first finished ???

Comment: Have you made sure that you specifically set `loop: false` in options?

Comment: var playMovie = function(videos, currentVideoIdx, first) {

        if (!first)
            player.loadVideo(videos[currentVideoIdx % videos.length]).then(function(id) {
                player.play()
            }).catch(function(error) {
            });

        player.on('ended', function() {
            playMovie(videos, ++currentVideoIdx, false)
        });
    }